# Fast access to key in file (without loading whole file to memory)

Tags: c#, file-io, mobile, performance, hashtable

Background: I am writing a c# application for windows mobile which will search for Definitions (Scientific) from a dictionary from filesystem.
The file looks like this (file has 100K+ entries):

```
 Word1:Meanings(2)
-meaning 1 bla bla bla
-meading 2 bla bla bla
[...]
```

The user should be able to enter a word and get the meaning as fast as possible. Users will only look for 1 or 2 words. To do this, i created a second file with a sorted list with the actual word and the byte-offset in the dictionary file.
Example:

```
word1:12344
word2:32241
word3:298
```

I look through my "index" (simple loop through all lines and compare if equal) and then "random-access" the dictionary file using the byte-offset.
Problem is, this is still to slow. 
I tried loading the index into an array/list/hashtable but due to the slow io, this takes too long (about 20 seconds to load the index). This is bad because the user will generally only look for one word. 
Therefore, I am looking for some type of n-tree implementation which can work directly on the file (without traversing the whole index).
Does someone has a advise how to do this?
My current solution looks like this (but buggy and dirty):
The new index has this format:

```
a:FileOffsetInDictionary:FileOffsetOf"ab" //the first 2 character starting with a
b:FileOffsetInDictionary:FileOffsetOf"ba"
c:FileOffsetInDictionary:0 //"0" means that their are no words starting with "c" (just for example)
[...]
ab:FileOffsetInDictionary:FileOffsetOf"aba"
ac:FileOffsetInDictionary:878878 //(just some random values for illustration)
[...]
ba:FileOffsetInDictionary:456
[...]
aba:FileOffsetInDictionary:2342
[...]
```

And searching is done this way:

```
Users enter the word "Tree"
Look for "t" in index by looping through the index
if "t" found then goto FileOffsetOf2Digit
if "tr" found then goto FileOffsetOf3Digit
[...]
[actually recursively coded]
```

Comment: You are basically re-implementing indexed access to a database. Have you considered using a real database for your task, for example, SQL Server CE? It's a file-based database system that works perfectly fine on Windows Mobile and only requires you to include a few (small) DLLs with your application.

Comment: @Heinzi Thanks for your response. If it would be a real business application I would use a sql database. However, I love computer science and wanted to write something faster then a regular sql database :) My current goal is to show results after each key stroke ("tre" should list results for "tree", "trends")

Comment: Where is your code that reads from the file? That may have some performance problems we can help with.

Comment: You'd be hard-pressed to write something faster than a SQL database, even a file-based one. The whole point of a database is to optimize searching and filtering to be as fast as possible.

Comment: @Daniel T. It depends. I would argue that for my specific problem there should be a faster solutions then a RDMS.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer would probably be to tell you to use a [b-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) index which is ideal for a disk based index of this nature, or better yet if you are talking about mobile 6.5 and earlier you could use SQL CE database. And you can find a number of implementations, but failing that you could do the following.

Using something along the lines of your current index file idea, make each index record a fixed size. So if you know that the word will never be more than 50 char and the offset will fit in a four byte integer, you can create record entries in the index file that are 54 bytes (assuming ASCII for the words, adjust accordingly). Then you can perform a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search) on the index file rather than scaning the entire file to access each record.

Comment: Thanks! I have no idea how to access a b-tree directly from disk (file). I don't want to build the b-tree in memory because that would take to long. I will benchmark fixed fields + binary search for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you must implement this yourself, you should construct a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) of your entire corpus. This is faster than B-trees, Red-Black trees, or hashtables for known data, and can store partial matches. I.e. if you call it with "T" it will return the first instance of the character "T" in your corpus. If you then call it with "r" and supply the first instance of "T", it will return the first instance of "Tr" in the corpus without having to first search for "T"s and so on.

Comment: Actually, my "new" index kinda tries to construct a trie. I searched a lot on the internet and only found tries in memory. Any ressources of how to represent the trie in a "regular" file?

Comment: I have only used memory tries; they typically have poor locality of reference and are not great for disk access. I have heard of HAT tries to address this, check out http://crpit.com/confpapers/CRPITV62Askitis.pdf